# can delete table row by swiping, but not in edit mode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have the following code in a UITableViewDelegate:

```
  @IBAction func editButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    if weightsTableView.editing {
        editButton.title = "Edit"
        weightsTableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
    } else {
        editButton.title = "End Edit"
        weightsTableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        scale.weights.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let ws = scale.weights.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
    scale.weights.insert(ws, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)
}
```

I can delete an entry from the table by swiping without going into edit mode. When I go into edit mode, I can move entries in the table, but touching the delete icon does nothing.

I'm new to this. What am I missing?

As requested, here is the remainder of the table controller code:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return scale.weights.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("WeightSetCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WeightSetTableViewCell

    cell.gaugeLabel.text = scale.weights[indexPath.row].gauge
    cell.initialLabel.text = "\(scale.weights[indexPath.row].initial) " + scale.weights[indexPath.row].weightUnit
    cell.incrementLabel.text = "\(scale.weights[indexPath.row].increment) " + scale.weights[indexPath.row].weightUnit

    return cell
}
```

Additional information: I put a breakpoint on the if editingStyle == .Delete line. It is being called when I delete by swiping, but not when I go into editing mode and click on the delete icon.

Comment: Please add the rest of your controller, like cellForRowAtIndexPath etc. Also, how do you want it to work?

Comment: after deleting the element from array, Reload the tableview.

Comment: @DHEERAJ. No, don't do that.

Comment: As to how I want it to work: I would like to be able to delete by either method.

Comment: Or more precisely, I would like to be able to delete by both methods.

Answer (score 1):

Use this, looks better for me

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Destructive, title: "Delete") { action in
        // Update your datasource here
        tableView.reloadData() // Reload data
    }
    return [deleteAction]
}
```

Comment: Tried it. It made no difference. I could still delete by swiping, but not by touching the red delete button in delete mode.

Comment: Verify if the user interaction is enable on the UITableViewCell

Comment: If you mean "User Interaction Enabled" in the property inspector, it is.